# Unsupported operand TypeError with fmin_ncg

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

So I have a cost function I am trying to minimize with fmin_ncg from scipy.optimize. It seems to work okay if I just run it once, but I also wrote a bootstrapping script that resamples the data  and repeatedly minimizes the cost function to compute confidence intervals. After a few iterations of the bootstrapping script, i get the below error. It's not very informative. Does anyone know where it might be coming from?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 97, in <module>
    main(rat, cluster_parameter.main)
  File "bootstrap.py", line 83, in main
    t, i = estimator(resampled_data, RAT_CLUSTERS[rat])
  File "/home/matthew/Dropbox/Work/vocalization_analysis/cluster_parameter.py", line 176, in main
    args=(included_clusters,jumps), avextol=1e-5)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1252, in fmin_ncg
    callback=callback, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1365, in _minimize_newtoncg
    update = alphak * pk
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

I'm not really sure the relevant code to post for this question. Here's the cost function

```
def cost(x, *args):
theta = x[0]
b = x[1]
included_clusters = args[0]
jumps = args[1]

h = [(n,SLOPES[n](theta)) for n in included_clusters]
h = OrderedDict(h)
bisecting_slopes = find_bisector(h)
vertices = polygon_vertices(bisecting_slopes, included_clusters)
cluster = poly_cluster(jumps[:,0:2], vertices)
cost = 0 
for c in h.keys(): 
    idx = find(cluster==c)
    l = len(jumps[idx,0:2])
    print(l)
    for j in jumps[idx,0:2]:
        x = (j[0] / h[c] + j[1] - b) / (h[c] + 1 / h[c])
        y = h[c] * x + b 
        cost += (((j[0] - x)**2 + (j[1]-y)**2)) / l 

#print('b='+str(b))
#print('theta='+str(theta))
#print('cost='+str(cost))
return cost
```

and here's it derivative

```
def dcost(x, *args):
theta = x[0]
b = x[1]
included_clusters = args[0]
jumps = args[1]

h = [(n, SLOPES[n](theta)) for n in included_clusters]
h = OrderedDict(h)
dh = [(n, DSLOPES[n](theta)) for n in included_clusters]
dh = OrderedDict(dh)
bisecting_slopes= find_bisector(h)
vertices = polygon_vertices(bisecting_slopes, included_clusters)
cluster = poly_cluster(jumps[:,0:2], vertices)

dcost_theta = 0
dcost_b = 0
for c in h.keys(): 
    idx = find(cluster==c)
    l = len(jumps[idx,0:2])
    for j in jumps[idx,0:2]:
        x = (j[0] / h[c] + j[1] - b) / (h[c] + 1 / h[c])
        y = h[c] * x + b 
        dx_theta = ((h[c]**2 + 1) * (j[1] - b) * dh[c] - 
            2 * (j[0] + (j[1] - b) * h[c]) * h[c] * dh[c]) / (h[c]**2 + 1)**2
        dy_theta = ((h[c]**2 + 1) * (j[0] * dh[c] + 2 * (j[1] - b) * h[c] * dh[c]) 
            - 2 * (j[0] * h[c] + (j[1] - b) * h[c]**2) * h[c] * dh[c]) / (h[c]**2 + 1)**2
        dx_b = -h[c] / (h[c]**2 + 1)
        dy_b = -h[c]**2 / (h[c]**2 + 1)

        dcost_theta += (2 * (j[0] - x) * dx_theta 
            + 2 * ((j[1] - b) - y) * dy_theta) / l

        dcost_b += (2 * (j[0] - x) * dx_b 
            + 2 * ((j[1] - b) - y) * dy_b) / l

return np.array([dcost_theta, dcost_b])
```

Also here is my main function. It just calls fmin_ncg.

```
def main(jumps, included_clusters = range(NUM_CLUSTERS)):
theta_min, b_min = fmin_ncg(f=cost, x0=[0,0], fprime=dcost,
 args=(jumps, included_clusters), avextol=1e-5, disp=0)

return theta_min, b_min
```

If you want to check out the rest of the program, you can here https://github.com/mdornfe1/vocalization_analysis/blob/error_analysis/cluster_parameter.py and here https://github.com/mdornfe1/vocalization_analysis/blob/error_analysis/bootstrap.py.

Comment: What Scipy version do you have? IIRC, this is a bug that has been fixed. However, if so, the failure is due to fmin_ncg not finding an acceptable descent direction --- upgrading Scipy won't help you here, as the algorithm then reports that it failed to converge to an acceptable solution. I would double-check the derivative function for correctness, as a wrong gradient will cause problems of this type.

Comment: I have scipy version 0.12.0. I can check again, but I feel like the derivative function is correct. When I run the bootstrap algorithm, I call fmin_ncg many times. It's not until I 30th or 40th time its called that the error is thrown.

Comment: I would suggest that you edit the main code so that it has the leading blanks and shows up more readbly. Also, show how you call it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the significant statement as far as you are concerned.

```
File "bootstrap.py", line 97, in <module>
    main(rat, cluster_parameter.main)
```

This means that he error is **not** occurring with your defined functions but is occurring within your main as you try to get the arguments. Please show the main and how you call the program. It seems as if you have invalid arguments.  argparse (or optparse if you have Python 2.6.7) might be useful here as part of the setup.

Comment: I added the main function to the original post. All it does is called fmin_ncg.